# How to disable retries with quarkus smallrye reactive messaging MutinyEmitter

Tags: quarkus, mutiny, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I would like to know if there is a way to configure retries when using io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.MutinyEmitter.
As per the [documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#retrying-processing) it seems possible to configure retry policies only when using @Incoming/@Outgoing annotations.

Answer (score 1):

After a deeper reading of the documentation i found the answer:

[Screen of the doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rS6m.png)